# How to upload a photo from form of .gsp file save it to some folder and save its link to database?

Tags: grails, file-upload, gsp

so far I have tried using:
At controller:

```
if(employeeInstance.save (flush:true)) {
    def profilePicture = request.getFile('profilePicture')
        if (!profilePicture.isEmpty()) {
            userInstance.avatar = fileUploadService.uploadFile(profilePicture, "${userInstance.id}.png", "profilePicture")
        }
    }
```

In this code i having error at request.getFile('profilePicture') as i my IDE is not giving any option of getFile('') when i do "ctrl+space" at request.
At .gsp File:

```
<form action="save">
    <input type='file' name='profilePicture'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

At service:

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder

class FileUploadService {
    boolean transactional = true

        def String uploadFile(MultipartFile file, String name, String destinationDirectory) {

            def servletContext = ServletContextHolder.servletContext
            def storagePath = servletContext.getRealPath(destinationDirectory)

            // Create storage path directory if it does not exist
            def storagePathDirectory = new File(storagePath)
            if (!storagePathDirectory.exists()) {
                print "CREATING DIRECTORY ${storagePath}: "
                if (storagePathDirectory.mkdirs()) {
                    println "SUCCESS"
                } else {
                    println "FAILED"
                }
            }

            // Store file
            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                file.transferTo(new File("${storagePath}/${name}"))
                println "Saved file: ${storagePath}/${name}"
                return "${storagePath}/${name}"

            } else {
                println "File ${file.inspect()} was empty!"
                return null
            }
        }
}
```

SO i am stuck here any help to upload image in some drive then save the link of that image at mysql database??

Answer (score 0):

For first use g:uploadForm not form, or in the form add

```
`enctype='multipart/form-data'`
```

base directory of project you can find by

```
System.properties['base.dir']
```

I wish it must be help you.